# How to check if a process started in the background still running?

Tags: go

It looks like if you create a subprocess via [exec.Cmd](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd) and [Start()](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Start) it, the `Cmd.Process` field is populated right away, however `Cmd.ProcessState` field remains `nil` until the process exits.

> ```
>    // ProcessState contains information about an exited process,
>    // available after a call to Wait or Run.
>    ProcessState *os.ProcessState
> ```

So it looks like I can't actually check the status of a process I `Start()`ed while it's still running?

It makes no sense to me `ProcessState` is set when the process exits. There's an [ProcessState.Exited()](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#ProcessState.Exited) method which will always return `true` in this case.

---

So I tried to go this route instead: `cmd.Process.Pid` field exists right after I `cmd.Start()`, however it looks like [os.Process](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process) doesn't expose any mechanisms to check if the process is running.

[os.FindProcess](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FindProcess) says:

> On Unix systems, FindProcess always succeeds and returns a Process for the given pid, regardless of whether the process exists.

which isn't useful –and it seems like there's no way to go from [os.Process](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process) to an [os.ProcessState](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#ProcessState) unless you `.Wait()` which defeats the whole purpose (I want to know if the process is running or not before it has exited).

Comment: Doesn't `ProcessState.Exited()` returning `false` tell you it's still running?

Comment: Don't you know if it's running or not depending on whether `Wait()` returned?

Comment: I don’t really wanna .Wait() but it looks like thats my only option. The answer below was pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have two reasonable options here:

- Spin off a goroutine that waits for the process to exit.  When the wait is done, you know the process exited.  (Positive: pretty easy to code correctly; negative: you dedicate an OS thread to waiting.)
- Use `syscall.Wait4()` on the published `Pid`.  A `Wait4` with `syscall.WNOHANG` set returns immediately, filling in the status.

It might be nice if there were an exported `os` or `cmd` function that did the `Wait4` for you and filled in the ProcessState.  You could supply `WNOHANG` or not, as you see fit.  But there isn't.

---

The point of `ProcessState.Exited()` is to distinguish between all the various possibilities, including:

- process exited normally (with a status byte)
- process died due to receiving an unhandled signal

See [the stringer for ProcessState](https://golang.org/src/os/exec_posix.go?s=2254:2862).  Note that there are more possibilities than these two ... only there seems to be no way to *get the others into* a `ProcessState`.  The only calls to `syscall.Wait` seem to be:

- `syscall/exec_unix.go`: after a failed `exec`, to collect zombies before returning an error; and
- `os/exec_unix.go`: after a call to `p.blockUntilWaitable()`.

If it were not for the `blockUntilWaitable`, the `exec_unix.go` implementation variant for `wait()` could call `syscall.Wait4` with `syscall.WNOHANG`, but `blockUntilWaitable` itself ensures that this is pointless (and the goal of this particular `wait` is to wait for exit anyway).